# How to escape plugin notation in App::uses() for CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf

I'm using CakePHP 2.7 and want to use a Vendor class by stating

```
App::uses('TCPDF', 'tecnick.com/tcpdf');
```

Cake complains because it is trying to load a file from the tecnick plugin.

I actually am aiming for a vendor class in `/vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf`. The confusion is obviously caused by the `.` in the vendor filepath.

How do I escape the dot in `App::uses()`?

Comment: Not escaping, still an alternative: `require_once APP . 'Vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use App::import, plugin should be in App/Vendor folder and full stop needs to be escaped:

```
App::import("Vendor", "tecnick\.com/tcpdf.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`App::uses('TCPDF', '.tecnick.com/tcpdf.php');`

Or use

`App::import('vendor', 'TCPDF', array('file' => 'tecnick.com/tcpdf.php'))`